# Help with Appspot regex

Tags: regex

Can someone please tell me how the following regex resolves? I am trying to upload an app to Appspot, and am getting an error that my name does not meet the following criteria:

```
^(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{1,100}$
```

Comment: woah. that's a pretty hair-raising regex just for name field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty complex, but I'll try and boil the rules down to English.

1. There is only one tilde (~) allowed in the name, but it is optional. If there is a tilde, it must not be the first character in the name, it must have at least 1 and at most 100 letters, numbers or dashes in front of it.
2. There is only one colon (:) allowed in the name, and it is optional. If there is a colon, it must:

   a. come after the tilde, if present.

   b. come after 1 or more letters, numbers, dashes or full stops.

   c. the group of letters, numbers, dashes and full stops cannot start with a dash.
3. The rest of the name can contain any letter, number or dashes, up to a hundred characters. The optional tilde and colon sections must come before it, and it cannot start with a dash. You must use at least one character, and at most 100.

Some examples that are allowed:

- foo~bar.baz:spam-eggs
- something:other-
- whomever~thought-this-was-a-good-idea
- together.we.stand:strong
- simply-should-work
- -starting-dash~as.long.as.there.is.a:tilde-after-it

Some examples that won't be allowed:

- -no-starting-dash
- -no-starting-dash:with-a-colon-but-no-tilde
- no.full.stops.without.a.colon.after.it
- ~no-tilde-at-the-start
- :no-colon-at-the-start
- more~than~one:tilde:or:colon

Comment: So something like abcdefg should work?  I am only trying to enter a simply a-z only name, no dashes, dots, tildes, etc.  I'm wondering if its a bug on their end.

Comment: Yes, this regex would match such a simple name, with the third part.

Comment: Thanks!  So I guess it's Google's fault, not mine this time =)

Answer (score 1):

```
^ (anchor to start of string)

  Any character in "a-z\d-"
  At least 1, but not more than 100 times
  ~

? (zero or one time)

  zero-width negative lookahead
    -

  Any character in "a-z\d-."
  At least 1, but not more than 100 times
  :

? (zero or one time)
zero-width negative lookahead
  -

Any character in "a-z\d-"
At least 1, but not more than 100 times
$ (anchor to end of string)
```

Comment: So the tilde, the dash, the colon, and second dash are required?

Comment: @idyllhands - yeah. Seems to be from the regex. Its like any one of them is a must :)

Comment: No, the tilde is allowed once in the name, but is optional. If it is there, it needs to have between 1 and 100 characters before it (a-z, numbers, a dash).

Answer (score 1):

```
^                  # start of string
(?:                # Try to match the following:
 [a-z\d\-]{1,100}  # - 1-100 of the characters a-z, 0-9 or -
 \~                # - followed by a ~
)?                 # zero or one times.
(?:                # Then try to match:
 (?!\-)            # - unless the first character is a -
 [a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}# - 1-100 of the characters a-z, 0-9, . or -
 :                 # - followed by a :
)?                 # zero or one times.
(?!-)              # Then (unless the next character is a -) match:
[a-z\d\-]{1,100}   # 1-100 of the characters a-z, 0-9 or -
$                  # until the end of the string.
```